# Selecting sublists with distinct elements at various levels of a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, filtering

I have a list containing three vertices of several triangles in 3D space.

```
lst= {{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}}, {{-2, -4, -3}, {5, 1, 11}, {5,
    3, 11}}, {{-2, -4, -3}, {5, 10, 2}, {5, 10, 
   4}}, {{-2, -4, -3}, {8, -2, -1}, {8, 6, 7}}, {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 
   8, -3}, {8, -2, 7}}, {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 8, -3}, {8, 
   6, -1}}, {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 8, 9}, {5, 1, -5}}, {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 
   8, 9}, {5, 3, -5}}, {{-2, 5, -3}, {1, 10, 7}, {5, 6, 11}}}
```

How can triangle vertices be selected such that:

1. The vertices are made up of distinct integers. For example:

   `{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}}`
2. All columns have distinct integers. For example:

   `{{-2, 5, -3}, {1, 10, 7}, {5, 6, 11}}`

For the first column, $-2 \neq 1$, $-2 \neq 5$, $5 \neq 1$, etc. The number `5` can repeat but not in the same column.

I rarely use the command `Select` or `Pick`, therefore it's difficult for me to select.

Comment: I dont quite understand the rules you want to select.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interpreting the word "difference" in your question as "different" (Not sure, please check):

```
Select[lst, ( 9 == Length[Union @@ #] &)]
(* {{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}}} *)

Select[lst, ( And @@ (Unequal @@@ Transpose[#]) &)]
(* {{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}}, {{-2, 5, -3}, {1, 10, 7}, {5, 6, 11}}} *)
```

Comment: You understand me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @minthao_2011 You're welcome. Please edit your question to make it easier to understand for future readers

Comment: Yes. I will edit my question.

Comment: @ belisarius In line `Select[lst, ( 9 == Length[Union @@ #] &)]` If I want 9 numbers different from 0. How can I select?

Comment: @minthao_2011 `Select[lst, (9 == Length[Union @@ #] && Times @@ (Union @@ #) != 0 &)]`

Comment: If each element contains four points, for example,  `{{-5, -1, -1}, {-5, -1, 3}, {-5, 4, -2}, {3, -1, -5}}`. I tried
`Select[nonright, (12 == Length[Union @@@ #] &)]` it does not correct. Please help me.

Comment: I am sorry. I did.

Answer (score 4):

Using point-free syntax:

```
lst = {{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}}, {{-2, -4, -3}, {5, 1, 
    11}, {5, 3, 11}}, {{-2, -4, -3}, {5, 10, 2}, {5, 10, 
    4}}, {{-2, -4, -3}, {8, -2, -1}, {8, 6, 7}}, {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 
    8, -3}, {8, -2, 7}}, {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 8, -3}, {8, 
    6, -1}}, {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 8, 9}, {5, 1, -5}}, {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2,
     8, 9}, {5, 3, -5}}, {{-2, 5, -3}, {1, 10, 7}, {5, 6, 11}}};

Select[EqualTo[9]@*Length@*Apply[Union]][lst]

Select[Apply[And]@*Map[Apply[UnsameQ]]@*Transpose][lst]
```

---

**Using `DistanceMatrix`:**

```
lst /. x_?MatrixQ :> Flatten[x] /. 
   x_?VectorQ :> Count[DistanceMatrix[x], 0, {2}] // Position[9] // 
 Extract[lst, #] &

lst /. x_?MatrixQ :> Transpose[x] /. 
   x_?VectorQ :> Count[DistanceMatrix[x], 0, {2}] // 
  Position[{3, 3, 3}] // Extract[lst, #] &
```

---

*Results:*

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}}}
>
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}}, {{-2, 5, -3}, {1, 10, 7}, {5,
> 6, 11}}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list =
  {{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}},
   {{-2, -4, -3}, {5, 1, 11}, {5, 3, 11}},
   {{-2, -4, -3}, {5, 10, 2}, {5, 10, 4}},
   {{-2, -4, -3}, {8, -2, -1}, {8, 6, 7}},
   {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 8, -3}, {8, -2, 7}},
   {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 8, -3}, {8, 6, -1}},
   {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 8, 9}, {5, 1, -5}},
   {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 8, 9}, {5, 3, -5}},
   {{-2, 5, -3}, {1, 10, 7}, {5, 6, 11}}};
```

Case 1

```
Cases[{{_, _, _} ..}] @ Map[UniqueElements, list]
```

{{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}}}

Case 2

```
Pick[list, And @@ Map[DuplicateFreeQ] @ Transpose[#] & /@ list]
```

{{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}}, {{-2, 5, -3}, {1, 10, 7}, {5,
6, 11}}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list =
  {{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}},
   {{-2, -4, -3}, {5, 1, 11}, {5, 3, 11}},
   {{-2, -4, -3}, {5, 10, 2}, {5, 10, 4}},
   {{-2, -4, -3}, {8, -2, -1}, {8, 6, 7}},
   {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 8, -3}, {8, -2, 7}},
   {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 8, -3}, {8, 6, -1}},
   {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 8, 9}, {5, 1, -5}},
   {{-2, -4, 9}, {-2, 8, 9}, {5, 3, -5}},
   {{-2, 5, -3}, {1, 10, 7}, {5, 6, 11}}};
```

Using `CountDistinct` and `Pick`:

**Case 1**:

```
Pick[#, 9 == CountDistinct[Flatten@#] & /@ #] &@lst
```

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}}}

**Case 2**:

```
f = 3 == CountDistinct@# & /@ Transpose@# &;

Pick[#, MatchQ[#, {True ..}] & /@ (f /@ #)] &@lst
```

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -4}, {5, 6, 10}}, {{-2, 5, -3}, {1, 10, 7}, {5, 6, 11}}}